# I want to know if this query method is possible?

Tags: sql

I have this Query

```
    SELECT     PaymentDetails_ID AS Pay_ID, Type, Description, Details, Due_Date,    PaymentDetails_Cleared, Amount, Mode,
                          (SELECT     Bill_ID
                            FROM          Bill_Payment_Records
                            WHERE      (Payment_ID = Pay_ID)) AS Bill_No
FROM         Payment_Details
WHERE     (Mode = 1) AND (PaymentDetails_Cleared = 0) AND (Due_Date BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date)
```

over here i want to add a variable which can be used in an inside query.
Like i want Bill_ID which can be determined in the query.

As i studied i don't think its possible but is there any way i can do that.

Comment: That layout isn't exactly easy to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're having trouble with the calculation for [Bill_No].  There are three possible issues I can think of, the first of which I'm quite sure is the main problem:
1. [Pay_ID] is actually [PaymentDetails_ID].  You can't use the alias inside the same SELECT statement where you assign the alias.
2. You don't specify the table names in the correlated sub-query.
3. You may get more than 1 record back from the correlated sub-query.

Try this?

```
SELECT
   PaymentDetails_ID AS Pay_ID,
   Type,
   Description,
   Details,
   Due_Date,
   PaymentDetails_Cleared,
   Amount,
   Mode,
   (
      SELECT
         TOP 1
         Bill_ID
      FROM
         Bill_Payment_Records
      WHERE
         [Bill_Payment_Records].Payment_ID = [Payment_Details].PaymentDetails_ID)
   ) AS Bill_No
FROM
   Payment_Details
WHERE
   (Mode = 1)
   AND (PaymentDetails_Cleared = 0)
   AND (Due_Date BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date)
```

(Only the "TOP 1" and table names were added to the correlated sub-query.  "Pay_ID" was changed to "PaymentDetails_ID".)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your question but according to me you can use variable inside select statement like this added @billid in query

```
SELECT     PaymentDetails_ID AS Pay_ID, Type, Description, Details, Due_Date,    PaymentDetails_Cleared, Amount, Mode,
     (SELECT     Bill_ID
          FROM          Bill_Payment_Records
          WHERE      (Payment_ID = @billid)) AS Bill_No
         FROM         Payment_Details
    WHERE     (Mode = 1) AND (PaymentDetails_Cleared = 0) AND (Due_Date BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date)
```

Comment: i know that but that billed variable is to be generated during this query execution

Comment: post your query than i can give solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

That is possible but not right way to do because it's like you put fixed value in the Query
unless you use loop or Cursor for running Query.

Comment: Can you suggest me something to read or any link 
may be any example

Comment: Declare @bill_ID as int
Declare Cursor as select Query for your use
into Variables list which you want in Cursor
begin
use your Sub Query and set your variable in the 
Select @BillID = BillId from TableName where Criteria
User your Original Query and put @BillID in this.
Select * from Tablename where Billid=@BillID
end
Deallocate Cursor

Comment: i was not able to perform that. Can you be more specific. :$